# 2007 Access Update query not working

Tags: ms-access

Below is my query:

```
UPDATE CASReport SET [Format Code] = (
     SELECT f.[Format Code] 
     FROM lkup_formatCode f
     INNER JOIN CASReport c
     ON c.Channel = f.Channel AND
     c.Format = f.Format
);
```

When I run the query I get a popup with the message "Operation must use an updateable query."  Please help.

Answer (score 0):

In the query properties, try changing the RecordSourceType to `Dynaset (Inconsistent Updates)`